# Nuclide remotee development setup with anaconda on the server side

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I am using nuclide and nuclide-server for remote development for Python. However, the anaconda / virtualenv envirionment is on the server side. How do I make sure that I am inside the anaconda / virtualenv environment?

For example, do I need to do this:

1. source activiate ...blah...
2. start the nuclide-server inside the virtualenv

so that I can make sure that the nuclide-server is inside my desired virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a shell script on your remote server that should consist of:

1. initialization of your environment
2. any other preparation
3. and finally running the nuclide-start-server command

After your script is done, it should be somewhere in your $PATH so you could fill the script's name in the Remote Server Command field as shown in the [image: screenshot].

Comment: I think even if I create start the remote server inside virtual env atom still doesn’t know to find the dependency in the remote machine. Instead tried to find it locally

Comment: It is working for me! I run custom script with:
    `export PATH=$HOME/path/to/virtualenv/bin:$PATH:$(npm bin)`
    `exec /usr/bin/nuclide-start-server $@`